# Как удалить определенную строку из текстового документа python

Tags: python, ос, sys

У меня есть код который берет ники(одна строка - один ник) из текстового документа, подставляет его к ссылке и проверяет статус страницы. Я столкнулся с проблемой при удалении проверенной строки.
Вот код самого чекера:

```
def a():
    try:
        print(f'{Fore.WHITE}----------------------------------------\n{Fore.YELLOW} Начинаем проверять ники из базы...\n{Fore.WHITE}----------------------------------------')
        with open(r"nicks.txt", "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                name = line
                r = requests.get(f'https://replit.com/@{name}')
                if r.status_code == 200:
                   print(f'{Fore.GREEN}[+] https://replit.com/@{name}/')
                   valid = f'https://replit.com/@{name}/'
                   with open(r"valid.txt", "a") as file:
                       file.write(valid + '\n')
    except:
        pass
```

Как сдать так, чтобы после проверки строка удалялась. Все чего я добился, это полная очистка файла.

Comment: Два контекстных менеджера с open, которые обрабатываются, как одна переменная. Назовите их по разному

Answer (score 1):

Накидал правку. Немного убрал необъявленных переменных. `for line in file1` заменил на `for name in file1` потом лишний раз ее переопределяете.

Также стоит отметить, что если Вы проверяте только существование страницы, то проще делать запрос не `requests.get()`, а `requests.head()`

```
def a():
    try:
        print("""----------------------------------------\nНачинаем проверять ники из базы...\n----------------------------------------""")
        with open("nicks.txt", "r") as file1, open("valid.txt", "w") as file2:
            for name in file1:
                if requests.head(f'https://replit.com/@{name}').status_code == 200:
                    print(f'[+] https://replit.com/@{name}/')
                    file2.write(f'https://replit.com/@{name}/\n')
    except:
        pass
```